# How to link csv file in Libreoffice 5

Tags: csv, libreoffice

In previous versions of Libreoffice Calc, it was straightforward to import and link csv files through [Import] -> [Sheet from file...], as per the instructions on [this page](http://blog.louic.nl/?p=622). This allowed me to refresh the sheet as the linked csv changed.

With the introduction of Libreoffice 5, I find that the option is missing. Is there an easy way to reproduce this functionality in the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is still there, just in a different place.

1. Right-click on the sheet tab at the bottom and select `Insert Sheet`.  Or go to `Sheet -> Insert Sheet`.
2. Choose the `From file` radio button.
3. Check the `Link` check box.
4. Browse to the file.

To update the file later, go to `Edit -> Links` as before.